# R code execution using : system time()

Tags: algorithm, r, matlab

I have some code that I ported from Matlab to R. I want to compare their performance.

However, I encountered a problem: Using `system.time()` in R, but I get different results for the same code. Is this supposed to happen? How do I compare it?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but always keep in mind that you aren't just comparing R vs Matlab, you're also comparing your ability to write code that takes the most advantage of both languages.

Comment: Thank you joran! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 6):

You'll get different results if you time your self running a 100m sprint too!  The computer has lots of things going on that will slightly vary the time it takes to run your code.

The solution is to run the code many times.  The R package `benchmark` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! ;) i was thinking it might be this situation , but in my network noone knows R so they cant explain the figures!

Answer (score 0):

As @Justin said, the times will always vary. Especially the first time couple of times, since the garbage collection system hasn't adjusted itself to your specific use. It might be a good idea to restart R before measuring (and close other programs, ensure the system isn't scanning for viruses at this time etc)...

Note that if the measured time is small (fractions of a second), the relative error will be rather large, so try to adjust the problem so it takes at least a second.

The packages `benchmark` or `rbenchmark` can help.

...but I typically just do a for-loop around the problem and adjust it until it takes a second or so - and then I run it several times too.

Here's an example:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    sum <- 1
    for (i in seq_along(x)) sum <- x[[i]] + y[[i]] * sum
    sum
}

n <- 10000
x <- 1:n + 0.5
y <- -1:-n + 0.5
system.time(f(x,y)) # 0.02-0.03 secs 

system.time(for(i in 1:100) f(x,y)) # 1.56-1.59 secs
```

...so calling it 100 times reduced the relative error a lot.

Comment: The time used are the operating system's counters for process times.  These are sampled values, and are normally fairly accurate.  But they can produce very wrong results, if there is a competing process that is driven by a timer of just the "wrong" frequency (OS dependant, for OpenVms AXP it's multiples of 10ms).

Comment: Thank you! It helps me to understand!